# Computer security question migrated to bitcoin.SE

Tags: discussion, migration

I wrote a question about avoiding single point of trust in online asset management services. I used Bitcoin as an example since it's a well understood example.

It was migrated to bitcoin.SE ([here's a link](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49974/how-to-avoid-single-point-of-trust-in-online-bitcoin-exchange-sites)). I think this was unfortunate because, while the bitcoin.SE users are probably good with bitcoin related questions such as the protocol and cryptography, this question was more about computer security.

Any chance this could be migrated back to security.SE? Or is there a particular reason this question is not suited for security.SE?

Comment: It doesn't look like a security question to me. At least not within our site scope.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm basically wondering if there's a security mechanism / routine / procedure to ensure that a single person could not run away with a company's assets. Is the question itself off topic (if so why)? or is it just poorly formulated?

Comment: I agree that the migration was strange. You could easily replace "bitcoin" with "average bank" without changing the main point of the question. Just because a question contains the word bitcoin does not mean it is about bitcoins.

Comment: It might still not be a good question for this site - in my personal opinion it is to broad. But I think migrating was not the correct thing to do.

Comment: Conversation is in [chat]

Comment: @RoryAlsop, I think it's fine having a conversation here too, as long as it's on topic and short.

Comment: It already isn't - and comments are considered temporary, so let's keep conversation to chat.

Comment: No, all comments are not considered temporary. That would be a bit absurd if you ask me. The type of comments Anders posted above are precisely the type of discussions that typically go on in these types of posts on meta-sites.

Comment: @aioobe Comments are absolutely temporary, by design.  See [the canonical explanation of commenting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/214521) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple. I migrated your question because it was Bitcoin-specific (not just containing the word "bitcoin"). That community would have the knowledge to understand how the mechanisms in Bitcoin would address the issue.

You edited the question afterwards to be more general, but the question when I reviewed it would have had a specific technical answer that that community could address better than ours.

Comment: Did not notice the edit when I wrote my previous comment - with the question in its original shape the mirgration makes sense to me.